# Showing that if a real-valued function on a subset $A$ of $E^n$ is reimann integrable, then it is also integrable on a subset $B$

Tags: real-analysis

These are all reimann integrable not necessarily lebesgue.

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on a subset $A$ of $E^n$ and let $B \subset A$ Show that if $\int_{A} f$  exists and B has volume then $\int_{B} f$ exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on what that notation means?

Comment: Should there be absolute values? What if the function takes on a larger proportion of negative values in B than A?